# Testing Ecto 2.0 in an umbrella app

Tags: elixir, ecto, ex-unit

I am trying to set up an app under umbrella that will handle the business logic. It uses Ecto for interacting with the database. I’m having problems with setting up SQL.Sandbox for testing. Whenever I run test, I get this error:

```
$ MIX_ENV=test mix test
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(Domain.Repo.Pool, :checkin, 5000)
  ** (EXIT) no process
  (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:596: GenServer.call/3
  lib/ecto/adapters/sql/sandbox.ex:422: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode/2
  (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
  (elixir) lib/enum.ex:651: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
  (elixir) lib/enum.ex:651: Enum.each/2
```

My config.exs looks like this:

```
use Mix.Config

config :domain,
  ecto_repos: [Domain.Repo]

config :domain, Domain.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "app_test"
```

My test_helper.exs is:

```
ExUnit.start()
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Domain.Repo, :manual)
```

Comment: I believe you need to add the following to the `setup` block of the test modules (Phoenix does this): `:ok = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(Domain.Repo)`. Could you try that out?

Comment: I just added the following to the tests, still the same behaviour:

`setup do
  :ok = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(Domain.Repo)
end`

Comment: Ah, I misread the error. You need to start `Domain.Repo` before the tests. If this package has an `Application`, try adding `supervisor(Domain.Repo, [])` to its children list, otherwise try adding `Domain.Repo.start_link()` after `ExUnit.start()`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(EXIT) no process` in `GenServer.call` means that the server you tried to send a call request to is not currently alive. You'll have to ensure `Domain.Repo` is running before you call `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Domain.Repo, :manual)`.

The most common way is to add `Domain.Repo` as a `Supervisor` to the `Application`'s supervision tree. To do this, add the following to the `children` list in `Domain.start/2`:

```
children = [
  ...,
  supervisor(Domain.Repo, []) # add this
]
```

If, for some reason, you only want to start the Repo in your tests, you can also add the following before calling `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Domain.Repo, :manual)` in `test/test_helper.exs`:

```
Domain.Repo.start_link()
```

Comment: The relevant bit for me was the last paragraph, I only needed to start the Repo while testing.